# Excel: how can I check if values in Column A uniquely identify set of values in Column B?

Tags: excel, vba, uniqueidentifier

I want to check if one column in an Excel file can be used as a unique identifier for data transformation purposes. Currently, I am comparing two columns, say Column A and Column B. I want to see if there is a one-to-one map between the set of values in Columns A and B.

Say the data looks like the below, then it is a positive outcome:

```
Column A     Column B
X            3
X            3
X            3
Y            5
Z            9
```

My idea was to do an `=PRODUCT()` formula of (number of unique values in B for each unique A) and if it is equal to 1, then it is a positive outcome. However, I'm not sure how to do this.

Can I do this with VBA? Essentially I just want a Boolean value as the output depending on whether it satisfies my condition.

Comment: Do you need VBA? This could be done with a formula: `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2),"Unique","NOT unique")`

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks! Good intro. to the COUNTIFS function.